# questions about the datetime type values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several things which I want to discuss with you guys.

Since, they were just simple questions, so no dataset here.

Suppose I have a datetime type column which called started_date, the value in it was like: 
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. So, if I want to select some IDs which were larger than one specified day (let's say June/01/2017), can I just using

```
select ID, started_date
from table1
where started_date>"2017-06-01";
```

Does this work?
I tried some samples, and it worked indeed in the mysql. However, someone told me that I cannot compare the datetime column with string values without converting their format. And it confused me. Because I thought the value "2017-06-01" here was date type value, so it does not need convert. Or am I thinking wrong?

Another thing was about the double quote and single quote, I understand that the single quote was used for string values. However, in this case, when I used double quote to quote "2017-06-01", it works. So, does it mean the double quote can quote date values?

I am just asking, so any response is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine.  You are using a safe date/time format for the string.  In other words, if you have to store the value as a string, then use that format.

I would write the code as:

```
where started_date >= '2017-06-01'
```

I see no reason to exclude midnight on 2017-06-01 (although you might have a reason).  Second, single quotes are the standard delimiter for strings.

That said, you can store the value as a string.

Comment: Thanks, and what is the most safe way?

Comment: @XiaoxiChen . . . Store the value using the correct data type in the database.

Answer (score 0):

As a best practice, I stay away from comparing time-stamps to date-stamps. In this case you can be explicit and truncate the start date. And yes, use single quotes instead.

```
where SUBSTR(started_date, 1, 10) > '2017-06-01'
```

Comment: Note that this cannot use an index. However, if you could reverse the comparison, then it could.

Comment: ty please explain further

Comment: `WHERE SOMETHING('2017-06-01') < started_date` can use an index

Answer (score 0):

To make sure it works you could just convert the date time to a string first and compare the two strings:

```
to_char(started_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2017-06-01'
```

The Strings will compare just fine in that format.